# How to write if and else statement more elegantly in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm having a bit of a brain fart in Swift and I know this code could be written better. Basically what it is, I have two images and I check if a value is over 3 to show an image and hide the other.
currently I have it like this

```
let greaterThanThree = value > 3 
image1.isHidden = greaterThanThree
image2.isHidden = !greaterThanThree
```

But I feel like there is a more elegant way to write this.

Comment: There is no way how you could improve/simplify this code. Only you can use an array for images (having `images[0]` and `images[1]`) but I would do that only if there were more than 2 images.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it like this:

```
image1.isHidden = value > 3 
image2.isHidden = !image1.isHidden
```

Anything shorter than that is just code golfing.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a rule here that exactly one of these two views should be visible at all times. If so, I'd create, as part of my view controller's `viewDidLoad`, an instance of this struct:

```
struct AlternateViews {
    let views : [UIView]
    init(_ v1:UIView, _ v2:UIView) {
        views = [v1,v2]
    }
    func hide(first:Bool) {
        views[0].isHidden = first
        views[1].isHidden = !first
    }
}
let alternateViews = AlternateViews(image1, image2)
```

Okay, that's a lot of work to set up initially, but the result is that later you can just say

```
self.alternateViews.hide(first: value > 3)
```

The struct is acting as a tiny state machine, making sure that your view controller's views remain in a coherent state. This technique of moving the rules for state into utility structs attached to your view controller is recommended in a WWDC 2016 video and I've been making a lot of use of it ever since.

If you have more pairs of alternating views, just make and maintain more instances of the struct.

(If the rule that I've assumed is not quite the real rule, make a struct that *does* express the real rule.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

`(image1.isHidden, image2.isHidden) =  (value > 3) ? (true, false) : (false, true)`

Basically if the value is greater than 3, the first image will be hidden and the second one won't. Otherwise, the second image will be hidden and the first one will not.